# Submitting form on link using php/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have template in which a button is created with a link using css, hence i want that button to submit form on that link, i tried but nothing happens, please help me, 
thanks.

```
<?php
$errors = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])=="Find Moving Service") {
echo 'Form Submitted!';
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm" >
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Find Moving Service"  />
<select name="category">
                <option value="" >Select a category</option>
                <option value="Local Movers" >Local Movers</option>
                <option value="Long Distance Movers" >Long Distance Movers</option>
                <option value="Office Movers" >Office Movers</option>
                <option value="International Movers" >International Movers</option> 
            </select>
        <a href="javascript: submitform()" title="Find Moving Service" class="button_big big_green float-right">Find Moving Service<i></i></a>
        </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  if(document.myForm.onsubmit())
  {
    document.myForm.submit();
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.myForm.submit();return false;" title="Find Moving Service" class="button_big big_green float-right">
```

And you don't need the function.

Comment: Tried it but link appear in #, nothing.. else thanx for reply.

Comment: @Bheem Forgot `return false;` Updated answer. try again.

Comment: ok, this works on removing if(isset($_POST['submit'])=="Find Moving Service") { ..... now for what php???? :D

Comment: @Bheem Right, my answer included the note to remove the function. The PHP is a separate question. If I answered your original question, please accept. Thanks.

Comment: @Bheem Post another question to SO. I have no idea what you want to do with the form data.

Answer (score -1):

try to put your javascript code before the body tags

Comment: i tried to put in <head></head> but again don't work.. thanks for reply